# How to change the initial state set in reducer from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have set the initial state in my redux reducer for login auth.Say `authError=null` on successful login I would like to change it. When I click logout, I want to set `authError = ''`.

Can I change to readonly state of reducer form a component?

**Component**

```
   const {authError} = this.props;
   this.setState(authError = "")
```

**Reducer**

```
 const initState = {
 authError : '',
 empname : 'test', phoneno:'321' 
 }

 const signin = (state = initState, action) => {

switch(action.type){
  case 'SIGN_IN':
    const empname = action.payload.empname;
    const phoneno = action.cred.phoneno;
    console.log('===============$$$=====================');
    console.log(empname, phoneno);
    console.log('===============$$$=====================');
    return {
      ...state,
      authError : null,
      empname,
      phoneno
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a readonly state of reducer?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot called `setState` on props. As **props** are used to customize Component when it’s being created and give it different parameters.

Unlike props, **state** is a private feature and it strictly belongs to a single Component. State allows React components to dynamically change output over time in response to certain events.

A **reducer** is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action as arguments and returns a new state.

In short reducer dispatches the application states to suitable components in form of props. If you want to change a value of prop from a component you need to define a **separate** action and modify value in that action & then you can return modified value .

You can easily get started by reading [this](https://alligator.io/react/react-native-redux)